# How to change constraints when device is in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

Is there a way to change the constraints?
I want to change the height, centerX and centerY of the button if the device is in landscape mode.

Comment: take IBOutlet of that constraint and change accordingly

Comment: Are you using storyboard or by code?

Comment: Currently storyboard

Comment: can you post some screen shot or code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use different constraints by using Size classes. Size classes allows you to add different constraints for various modes i.e landscape and Portrait for various devices.

Comment: And how can I change the height when my device is in landscape mode?

Comment: You can change the height by using two ways: 1)create outlet of height constraint and change it on rotation 2)Use <= relation for height constraint from storyboard.

Comment: If you are creating outlet of button's height constraint, then you will have to change it like YourbuttonHeightConstraintOutlet.constant = your_new_value

Comment: Then assign your button width constraint as equalWidth with your container view and change Multiplier property as 0.5

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto-Layout then make outlets of constraints and change your constraint's constant value as per your need.

Example: If your height constraint is heightOfView then set heightOfView.constant = x , in your landscape mode

Answer (score -1):

The size class will help you change the constraints in landscape and portrait mode both and even for the device screen ratio. For more details have a look at [Ray wenderlich Auto layout tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)